# how to optimize apex sharing trigger

Tags: trigger, apex-sharing

Hi I want to write a trigger on my custom object salesOrder__c whenever a record is inserted it has lookup to account (Sold_to_Party__c) I want to share sales Orders with all its accounts team members(Account already has records in its AccountTeamMember). Please help suggest optimize the code as I have queried inside for loop as I wanted to share all salesorder to all the AccountTeamMembers.

```
public static void sharetoTeam(List<Sales_Order__c> newList){
    list<Sales_Order__share> shareList = new list<Sales_Order__share>();

    for(Sales_Order__c shareObjt: newList){
        for (AccountTeamMember atm:[select id,UserId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId=:shareObjt.Sold_to_Party__c]){ 
            Sales_Order__share shareSO = new Sales_Order__share();
            shareSO.ParentId = shareObjt.Id;
            shareSO.UserOrGroupId = atm.UserId ;
            shareSO.AccessLevel = 'Read';
            shareSO.RowCause = 'Manual';
            shareList.add(shareSO);
        }
    }       
    Database.SaveResult[] shareInsertResult = Database.insert(shareList,false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should collect all values for Sold_To_Party__c above the loop and do a single query to retrieve all the team members for all those accounts;

```
Set<Id> soldToPartyIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Sales_Order__c shareObjt: newList){
    soldToPartyIds.add(shareObjt.Sold_To_Party__c);
}
List<AccountTeamMembers> members = [
    SELECT Id, UserId, AccountId 
    FROM AccountTeamMember 
    WHERE AccountId IN :soldToPartyIds
];
```

Then, set up a map from account id, to list of team members, so you can use them in your original loop;

```
Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMembers>> teamMembersPerAccount = new Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMembers>>();
for(AccountTeamMember member : members){
    //if we haven't seen this account yet, add an empty list to the map
    if(!teamMembersPerAccount.containsKey(member.AccountId)){
        teamMembersPerAccount.put(member.AccountId, new List<AccountTeamMember>());
    }
    //add the member to the list of the current account
    teamMembersPerAccount.get(member.AccountId).add(member);
}
```

Then you can change your inner for loop to

```
for(AccountTeamMember atm : teamMembersPerAccount.get(shareObjt.Sold_To_Party__c)){
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to iterate through the newList, create a map of sales_order__c by a key sold_to_party__c. Then query for accountTeamMember where accountIds are in the keys of the map. Then iterate through this queried list and from the map get the related Sales_order__c.

```
public static void sharetoTeam(List<Sales_Order__c> newList){
    list<Sales_Order__share> shareList = new list<Sales_Order__share>();
    Map<Id, Sales_Order__c> ordersByIds = new Map<Id, Sales_Order__c>();
    for (Sales_Order__c salesOrder : newList) {
        ordersByIds.put(salesOrder.Sold_to_Party__c, salesOrder);
    }
    for (AccountTeamMember atm : [select id, userid from AccountTeamMember where AccountId in:ordersByIds.keySet()]) {
        Sales_order__c shareObjt = ordersByIds.get(atm.AccountId);
        Sales_Order__share shareSO = new Sales_Order__share();
        shareSO.ParentId = shareObjt.Id;
        shareSO.UserOrGroupId = atm.UserId ;
        shareSO.AccessLevel = 'Read';
        shareSO.RowCause = 'Manual';
        shareList.add(shareSO);
    }
    Database.SaveResult[] shareInsertResult = Database.insert(shareList,false);
}
```

Comment: This will not exactly work if there are multiple sales orders for the same Sold To Party. In this case, you should use `Map<Id, List<Sales_Order__c>>`, to track all sales orders per Sold To Party.